# ¿Cómo borrar una rama remota que no existe en el servidor?

Tags: git, ramas-git

Hemos terminado de trabajar en una rama remota. Ya ha sido incorporada a producción y hay que borrarla.

Un compañero la ha borrado usando :

```
git push origin :rama_remota
```

Y, en efecto, ya no aparece en la interfaz web del repositorio. Ni al hacer un clone.
Pero `remotes/origin/rama_remota` sigue apareciendo en mi repositorio local y si intento borrarla tengo este error :

```
git push origin :rama_remota
error: unable to push to unqualified destination: rama_remota
The destination refspec neither matches an existing ref on the remote nor
begins with refs/, and we are unable to guess a prefix based on the source ref.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@mirepo.es:GIT/REPO.git'
```

Podría eliminarla usando prune:

```
#Primero miro cuales se borarrían
git remote prune origin --dry-run 
#Luego las borro
git remote prune origin
```

Pero resulta que hay bastantes ramas así. Y quiero borrar esta rama individual ahora y las otras cuando tenga tiempo de revisarlas.

Answer (score 1):

El error te aparece, porque al ejecutar *git push origin :rama_remota*, estas intentando acceder a una referncia que ya ha sido eliminada del repositorio, remoto. Entiendo que tu problema es que tienes una branch en tu repositorio local y deseas elminarla de este. eso se haría mediante el siguiente comando:

```
git branch -d nombre_de_la_branch_a_eliminar
```

Este comando simplemente borra la branch de tú repositorio local.
Espero poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Puede existir la posibilidad de que alguien más con acceso al repositorio haya borrado ya la rama que quieres borrar. Si esto pasa, obtendrás este mensaje al ejecutar el comando anterior:

> error: unable to push to unqualified destination: rama_remota
> The destination refspec neither matches an existing ref on the remote nor
> begins with refs/, and we are unable to guess a prefix based on the source ref.

Cuando esto pasa, necesitarás sincronizar tu lista de ramas del repositorio mediante el comando:

```
git fetch -p
```